# jq: only required fields if the field n is equal to x

Tags: jq

I have the following file:

```
[
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "OK",
  "result": {
    "query": "123",
    "hits": [
      {
        "ip": "2.14.11.41",
        "services": [
          {
            "port": 22,
            "service_name": "SSH",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 80,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 5900,
            "service_name": "VNC",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 8001,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "certificate": "62345a087218e",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "continent": "Asia",
          "country": "Israel",
          "country_code": "IL",
          "timezone": "Asia/Jerusalem",
          "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 31.5,
            "longitude": 34.75
          },
          "registered_country": "Israel",
          "registered_country_code": "IL"
        },
        "autonomous_system": {
          "asn": 12400,
          "description": "PARTNER-AS",
          "bgp_prefix": "2.54.0.0/17",
          "name": "PARTNER-AS",
          "country_code": "IL"
        },
        "last_updated_at": "2022-05-18T13:09:19.288Z"
      },
      {
        "ip": "2.22.22.102",
        "services": [
          {
            "port": 22,
            "service_name": "SSH",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 80,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 5901,
            "service_name": "VNC",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 8001,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "certificate": "6875897649b700a087218e",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 8089,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "continent": "Asia",
          "country": "Israel",
          "country_code": "IL",
          "city": "Herzliya",
          "timezone": "Asia/Jerusalem",
          "province": "Tel Aviv",
          "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 32.1679,
            "longitude": 34.834
          },
          "registered_country": "Israel",
          "registered_country_code": "IL"
        },
        "autonomous_system": {
          "asn": 12400,
          "description": "PARTNER-AS",
          "bgp_prefix": "2.55.0.0/17",
          "name": "PARTNER-AS",
          "country_code": "IL"
        },
        "last_updated_at": "2022-05-18T13:50:58.807Z"
      },
      {
        "ip": "4.54.84.19",
        "services": [
          {
            "port": 22,
            "service_name": "SSH",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 443,
            "service_name": "HTTP",
            "certificate": "8120978819a83e",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 502,
            "service_name": "MODBUS",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "port": 5900,
            "service_name": "VNC",
            "transport_protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "continent": "Asia",
          "country": "Israel",
          "country_code": "IL",
          "city": "Ashdod",
          "timezone": "Asia/Jerusalem",
          "province": "Southern District",
          "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 31.7915,
            "longitude": 34.6497
          },
          "registered_country": "Israel",
          "registered_country_code": "IL"
        },
        "autonomous_system": {
          "asn": 12400,
          "description": "PARTNER-AS",
          "bgp_prefix": "2.55.0.0/17",
          "name": "PARTNER-AS",
          "country_code": "IL"
        },
        "last_updated_at": "2022-05-18T12:36:13.141Z"
      }
    ],
    "links": {
      "next": "eyJ9I6MH0=",
      "prev": ""
    }
  }
}
]
```

I'm trying to get the following format out of it:

```
2.14.11.41:80
2.14.11.41:8001
2.22.22.102:80
2.22.22.102:8001
2.22.22.102:8089
4.54.84.19:443
```

i.e. select *IP* and port if *service_name* is equal to *HTTP*. I know how to get IP `jq -r '.[].result.hits[] | select(.services[].service_name == "HTTP") | .ip'` and also how to get only ports `jq -r '.[].result.hits[].services[] | select(.service_name == "HTTP") | .port'`, but I do not understand how to combine it properly in one command. Could someone please point to a right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the IP in a variable, and make your selection one level deeper. Then, print out if it matched:

```sh
jq -r '.[].result.hits[] | .ip as $ip | .services[] | select(.service_name == "HTTP") | "\($ip):\(.port)"'
```

```json
2.14.11.41:80
2.14.11.41:8001
2.22.22.102:80
2.22.22.102:8001
2.22.22.102:8089
4.54.84.19:443
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TUKX1QCj1Al)

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `jq` code. Concept wise same as already posted answer but a bit different in looping wise. Using `-r` option to get output in raw format, along with that using `select` function to check condition on service_name field is HTTP or not.

```
jq -r '.[].result.hits[] | "\(.ip):\(.services[] | select(.service_name=="HTTP").port)"' file
```